# SQL query problem

Tags: sql-server, database, function

I'm new to StackOverflow, and new to SQL Server, I'd like you to help me with some troublesome query.

This is my database structure(It's half spanish, hope doesn't matter)

[Database](http://bayimg.com/caeLFAADe)

My problem is that I don't now how to make a query that states which team is local and which is visitor(using table TMatch, knowing that the stadium belongs to only one team)

This is as far as I can get

```
Select P.NroMatch, (select * from fnTeam (P.TeamA)) as TeamA,(select * from fnTeam (P.TeamB)) as TeamB,
    (select * from fnEstadium (P.CodEstadium)) as Estadium, (cast(P.GolesTeamA as varchar)) + '-' + (cast(P.GolesTeamA as varchar)) as Score,
    P.Fecha
from TMatch P
```

Using this functions:

```
If object_id ('fnTeam','fn')is not null
drop function fnTeam
go
create function fnTeam(@CodTeam varchar(5))
returns table 

return(Select Name from TTeam where CodTeam = @CodTeam)
go

select * from fnTeam ('Eq001')
go
----****
If object_id ('fnEstadium','fn')is not null
drop function fnEstadium
go
create function fnEstadium(@CodEstadium varchar(5))
returns table 

return(Select Name from TEstadium where CodEstadium = @CodEstadium)
go
```

I hope I'd explained myself well, and I thank you help in advance

EDIT:

Thanks for the help, this is what I've been looking for

```
Select P.NroMatch, 
CASE 
    WHEN Ts.CodTeam= Ta.CodTeamTHEN Ta.Name
    ELSE Tb.Name
END 
As TeamLocal, 
CASE 
    WHEN Ts.CodTeam<> Ta.CodTeamTHEN Ta.Name
    ELSE Tb.Name
END 
As TeamVisitante,
Ts.Name as Estadium, 
(cast(P.GolesTeamA as varchar)) + '-' + (cast(P.GolesTeamB as varchar)) as Score,     
P.Fecha
from 
   TMatch P 
   join TTeamTa ON Ta.CodTeam= P.TeamA
   join TTeamTb ON Tb.CodTeam= P.TeamB
   join TEstadium Ts ON Ts.CodEstadium = P.CodEstadium
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to use 'lookup' functions for this (and shouldn't), joins are a better approach:

```
Select 
P.NroMatch, 
Ta.Name as TeamA,
Tb.Name as TeamB,     
Ts.Name as Estadium, 
cast(P.GolesTeamA as varchar)) + '-' + (cast(P.GolesTeamA as varchar) as Score,     
P.Fecha,
CASE 
    WHEN Ts.CodTeam = Ta.Name THEN Ta.Name
    ELSE Tb.Name
END As HomeTeam,
CASE 
    WHEN Ts.CodTeam <> Ta.Name THEN Ta.Name 
    ELSE Tb.Name 
 END As VistorTeam
from 
   TMatch P 
   join TTeam Ta ON Ta.CodTeam = P.TeamA
   join TTeam Tb ON Tb.CodTeam = P.TeamB
   join TEstadium Ts ON Ts.CodEstadium = P.CodEstadium
```

If you are new to SQL, it might be useful searching SO for some resources such as these:

[SQL Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

[SQL Tutorial](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/)

Comment: sorry, the datasabase is in the link(they don't let new users post images). Also, if TeamA and TeamB are playing in TeamA stadium, teamA is local

Comment: sorry for being so pushy but the problem is with the "visitor"

Comment: @Brisonela: I have no idea what you mean?